# Webcal URL using Aws API Gateway and AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

For the calendar, I want to create a sync URL like this:

> webcal://example.com/sync

Can this is possible using AWS API Gateway OR AWS Lambda.

AWS API Gateway allow to add domain then we can use that domain to call API. But can we call through webcal protocol?

I have searched a lot but not found any solution about it.

Comment: Hi - did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: @RossCoundon No. I didn't found anything about it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Luckily I found a way around the problem without needing to implement an API at all but, like you, couldn't find anything short of hosting a dedicated Baikal or equivalent server to implement a webcal endpoint